# image_tagとlink_toの組み合わせでエラーが起きます

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**前提・実現したいこと**
画像をリンクにしたい。

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

**該当のソースコード**

```
<%= link_to (image_tag(’/uploads/user/image/4/#{@user.image}’, { :border => ‘0’, :alt => ‘新規登録’}), current_user) %>
```

エディタ内では、#以降の色が変わり、アプリを起動するとエラーになります…

ちなみにこっちではエラーは起きていません。

```
<%= image_tag "/uploads/user/image/4/#{@user.image}" %>
```

マルチポスト
https://teratail.com/questions/55772?modal=q-comp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> シングルクォーテーションを半角に直しても、画像が表示されませんでした。
>
> ```
> <%= link_to image_tag('/uploads/user/image/4/#{@user.image}', {
> :border => '0', :alt => '新規登録'}), current_user %>
> ```
>
> 原因はわからないです…

Rubyの文字列リテラルでは、ダブルクォーテーションでは式展開が行われ、シングルクォーテーションでは行われないためではないでしょうか。

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/doc/spec=2fliteral.html#exp

Comment: そうなんですか！
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決。
(正確にはteratailでginさんから回答を受けました。)

【いただいた解答】
Rubyのことは分からないですが、依頼をもらったので気付いた点でもｗ 
該当のソースコードのシングルコーテーション全角なんですけど、これってRubyではOKなんですか？

【補足】
ちなみにシングルクォーテーションに直したらまた違う問題が起きたので、ついでに載せておきます。

最終的に画像をリンクにできたのはこのコードです。

```
<%= link_to current_user do %>
<%= image_tag "/uploads/user/image/4/#{@user.image}" %>
<% end %>
```

シングルクォーテーションを半角に直しても、画像が表示されませんでした。

```
 <%= link_to image_tag('/uploads/user/image/4/#{@user.image}', { :border => '0', :alt => '新規登録'}), current_user %>
```

原因はわからないです…

Comment: 他のサイトに答えが書かれている場合でも、要点を回答内に記載し、リンクはあくまで参考情報にとどめてください。リンク先が変更・削除された場合に回答の価値が失われることも防ぎます。 - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13451)

Comment: 直しました。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

`#{}` はシングルクォーテーション内では利用できません。
ダブルクォート内でのみ利用できます。

http://railsdoc.com/ruby_base

> ダブルクォート内の、「＃｛｝」は、式として評価された値が展開